# Sending the PHPSESSID with php curl cookie file

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I have 2 servers, each of which establish unique sessions and need to communicate back and forth.  I need to send the `PHPSESSID` cookie and get back the unique session cookie from my other server.

The way this needs to work is this:

> **Server A** sends a request with the `PHPSESSID` cookie 
>   **Server B** stores this id in a session, sends the `PHPSESSID` cookie back to **Server A** along with its own unique session id 
>   **Server A** validates the recieved `PHPSESSID` cookie against the current session and sends back an okay response with the current
>   session id and the unique session id from **Server B**
>  Finally
>   **Server B** checks that the recieved `PHPSESSID` from **Server A** matches that of the one in its own session, and that the unique
>   session id sent back from **Server A** still matches the one it sent
>   at the beginning of the request.

I'm using php cURL library along with `curlopt_cookiejar` and `curlopt_cookiefile`.  The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to send the `PHPSESSID` using a cookie file.  This is required to keep both the session ids persistent throughout the communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Use `CURLOPT_COOKIE` or `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option. You may also need to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to save the cookie from the request.

See http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#87112 for example.